# MIPS- Open a file with Strings of ints, convert them to ints and print

Tags: string, assembly, int, mips

Given a file with strings of numbers , how can i convert them to INTS then print them in MIPS? Any tips on where to start?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/Mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html) (pseudocode):

1. open the file (syscall #13)
2. read a number (syscall #14) (are they separed by commas, newlines, ...?)
3. convert into int (see below for a good algo)
4. output that int (syscall #1)
5. go to step 2

```
int ToInteger(char *digit)     // please note: destination base is 10!
{
    int result = 0;

    while (*digit) {
        result = (result * 10) + (*digit - '0');
        digit++;
    }

    return result;
}
```